# Degraded Kestrel Performance Over Increased Dormant Periods In Azure

Tags: asp.net, performance, azure, kestrel-http-server

We've been seeing some interesting behavior with our kestrel instances running on an Azure A2 Basic VM.  As time increases between calls, there appears to be a worsening degradation in response times.  For instance...

[image: Load Times]

Right around the 5min mark it behaves as if either the OS or Kestrel process had recycled some resources but the <del>linear</del> increase in response times following that 5 min mark is throwing us through a loop.

In addition this seems to happening intermittently when locally developing which is why the thought that Kestrel could be up to something hasn't been eliminated.

**Does anyone have thoughts on the 5min degradation and the subsequent worsening degradation?  Is this merely a symptom of using an A2 vm?**

<del>**What about the linear increase in time?**  I understand there's a limited number of data points and the increases could very well be an anomaly from a quick glance but this seems to be a common occurrence in day-to-day development.</del> *removed per lack of data points*

Comment: You really don't have enough data points to make a judgement on loading times, let alone determining that it's linear. In fact, it looks more like a step to me.

Comment: @DavidG I absolutely agree with you.  The data points are limited and it was merely a reflection of what we're seeing on a day-to-day basis.  Was hoping others might be experiencing something similar and shed some light on it.  What is this "step" you're referring to?

Comment: This is the step I'm referring to https://imgur.com/0mar3s3

Comment: Thanks, I understand what you're seeing now.  I updated the question to not have the linear assumption.

Comment: Are you using any [Singleton or Instance services](https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/fundamentals/dependency-injection.html#service-lifetimes-and-registration-options) through Dependency Injection that might be eating up memory? We are also using Kestrel and don't see that kind of behavior.

Comment: Yes, Autofac is being used with various single instance registrations. We didn't notice any memory spikes but I'll do a quick pass with a memory profiler to see if anything obvious sticks out.  Thanks for the idea.

Comment: There's really not enough information here to go by. The only thing that you've pointed out is the VM size you're using (A-series being the oldest and lowest-end available). Still that doesn't explain anything, but it's something to think about...

Comment: @MatiasQuaranta, switched all dependencies over to transient and still experiencing the same problem.

Comment: @DavidMakogon, trying out D-series to see if that helps.  Would prefer not masking the problem but at this point we might be spinning our wheels running on A2.  Thanks for the input.

Comment: Did you try running it on a Web App? Or do you need anything set up inside the VM?

Answer (score 0):

After doing some testing with additional tracing most of the performance degradation can be traced to establishing the connection to Azure SQL.  No "Min Pool Size" is specified in the default connection string generated in the Azure Portal.  This results in the default value of 0 being used.

After setting "Min Pool Size" to 5, response times after periods of inactivity improved.  After 21 minutes of inactivity the load time was still only 400ms.

We then specified no "Min Pool Size" (a default value of 0 is applied, resulting in no connections being kept open).  With this setting load times would grow to 4 or 5 seconds after periods of just 5 minutes of inactivity.